# LibVips pdf to jpg on specific pdf page for multi-page pdf

Tags: pdf, vips

I'm currently transforming pdfs to jpgs using the libvips command line.

```
vips jpegsave mypdf.pdf myimg.jpg
```

If a PDF is a multi page PDF then libvips will only transform the first page of the PDF. Is there a way to tell libvips which of the pages in the multi page pdf should be the one that gets transformed to a jpg?

Comment: Also asked and answered here: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/discussions/2126

Answer (score 2):

- Make a single jpeg with all pages

> vips copy "a.pdf[n=-1]" a.jpg

- Make a single jpeg with 2 pages

> vips copy "a.pdf[n=2]" a.jpg

- Make a single jpeg with second page

> vips copy "a.pdf[page=2]" a.jpg

Make a single jpeg - starting from second page of pdf and total of 3 pages

> vips copy "a.pdf[page=2,n=3]" a.jpg

Make multiple jpeg - from page i ( looping in bash - specific to linux )

> i=0;while vips copy "a.pdf[page=$i]" a$i.jpg; do ((i++)); done

Comment: thanks @jcuitt - i used the above link

Comment: Hi, I'm using this "i=0;while vips copy "a.pdf[page=$i]" a$i.jpg; do ((i++)); done"  and I always get pdfload: pages out of range even though all images are extracted successfully. Any reason why please?